# Error while disabling distribution in replication setup

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I was setting up a replication between Azure SQL Managed Instance and SQL on-premises. While deleting the distributor I have mistakenly deleted my distribution database from `Database → System Database Folder`.

Now I am not able to disable my distributer and getting the below error:

[image]

[image]

```
SQL Server could not disable publishing and distribution on 'testsqlmi97.public.7ec90fc2a898.database.windows.net, 3342'.

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

Invalid object name 'sysschemaarticles'.
Changed database context to 'master'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 208)
For help, click: https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-208-database-engine-error
```

Answer (score 0):

try use it

```
USE master
EXEC sp_removedbreplication @subscriptionDB
```

and

```
-- Remove the local server as a Distributor.
EXEC sp_dropdistributor;
```